# Link to etiquette is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, site-faq

If I go to https://askubuntu.com/faq and click on [this FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#etiquette), it doesn't take me to another section of the page.

Comment: It works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 8.0 on Windows XP.

Comment: Does anchor links on other pages work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This behavior depends on the browser, but it was broken in some cases (fixed in the next build).

We do something insanely hacky here because of how different browsers behave: **WE CHANGE YOUR LINKS!** We do this because we want the FAQ to be as accessible as possible and highlight exactly what was linked to (by copying it up top and giving it an eye-catching fade).

---

*Details:*
To get this effect but not have your browser jump immediately to the `#id` element in the page (from the URL hash) we actually change the IDs on all the sections from `#id` to `#link-id` (this is *explicitly* to prevent the jumping).

Now that we've broken everything, JavaScript compensates and our click handlers undo that `link-`-ification.  That wasn't happening in the full URL (`href="http://askubuntu.com/faq#etiquette"`) case like askubuntu has, it was only happening in hash (`href="#etiquette"`) case, this is fixed for the next build.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this in Firefox at all. I can click on the Etiquette section and it takes me that section of the page in the faq.

Comment: I tried it on Safari at home, and it didn't work. http://vimeo.com/35452993 ought to show the bug when the video's converted in half an hour's time.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - thanks for the video, that helped narrow it down quickly.  This bug depends on the browser (and event order), but should be fixed for everyone in the next build.

Comment: I've now deleted the video.